# no device connected while trying to connect firefox os handset with Firefox app-manager or webIDE

Tags: firefox, mobile, installation, firefox-os, usb-drive

I need help for the following issue..
I am trying to connect Symphony GoFox F15 handset of Firefox OS with Firefox nightly v36 (browser). but it says "no device connected". I installed ADB Add-ons also. I also tried using adb.exe of android. when I command "adb devices" it shows no device.

I googled for USB Driver for this handset and there i found only one website link which has been given below..

http://singledrivers.blogspot.com/2014/10/symphony-gofox-f15-usb-driver-for.html

But after downloading driver file, I followed the procedure but there it shows "no driver found" when i tried from device manager to update driver. May b file is missing. May b installing usb driver for this handset can solve this issue.. but don't know how to install it.

I am using windows 8 64 bit OS.

one more question.
In website it says it is OS version of 1.4 . but in handset setting details i found F15_0_000_V1.0_V09.2   . What does in mean then ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the device id (example: 0x1234) of that phone and you need to add it on ./android folder by updating the adb_usb.ini file.

Comment: Can you provide any guidance on finding the device ID?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion about it. This link will be helpful.
https://support.mozilla.org/ta/questions/1025935